# grails remotefunction more than one param

Tags: javascript, grails

I can send one param to the controller using the following in javascript:

```
 <g:javascript>

     var sel = "test";
     <g:remoteFunction action="newExisting" method="GET" update="updateThis" params="'sel='+sel"/>

 </g:javascript>
```

I cant figure out the syntax to add a second param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could pass clientside variables like :

```
params='\'param1=\'+sel+\'&booleanParam2=true\''
```

Comment: Thanks,
you can also do this:

        params="{'param1':sel , 'param2':listItemVal}"

Answer (score 2):

Another Way to pass multipale values like

```
params="[sel1: sel1,sel2:sel2]"
```

Comment: i posted this, too. And i think you can only add groovy-variables that way

Comment: no.. you posted with braces and i posted with square brackets.. ANd with square brackets its working with my code

Comment: much cleaner solution